# Forward/inverse search for Texmaker on OS X

Tags: mac, texmaker, forward-inverse-search

I have just started to use an Apple computer and want to use Texmaker. But forward/inverse search does not work at all. I am trying to follow the instructions but I'm not successful. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: I can't get it to work either. Have you considered using TeXShop http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/ instead? It's much more mature and a lot faster and synchs properly between PDF and source.

Comment: The Texmaker website only claims that Texmaker has forward/inverse search for DVIs. It doesn't say anything about PDFs. Maybe the problem is that you are compiling to PDF?

Comment: @Petya: I added an actual question to the question; hope that is okay. Maybe you could provide some details what exactly you have tried?

Comment: Have you tried a previous version of the software, I am using a portable version which works fine for me, you can download it from this address:

Comment: http://www.parsilatex.com/joomla/index.php?option=com_remository&Itemid=82&func=fileinfo&id=29

Comment: @Petya: Just to clarify the question, is it the source text that you want to search in or the compiled document?

Comment: @HeisenbOrg the idea of synctex is that you can click in the source or the pdf and it will link you back to the corresponding place in either version of your document.

Comment: Alan, look at my own answer - now it works like in Winedt or Texnicenter. I really spend a lots of time to understand it.

Comment: @Petya I'm glad you got it to work.  I would still take a look at TeXShop though :-)

Comment: @Alan, I know about TeXshop, but I am a switcher - just starting to use Mac after two decades of using Windows, and I just do not understand how to install it etc. Thank you!

Comment: @Petya Assuming you downloaded and installed MacTeX, it should already be installed, so there's really nothing to do except try it.  It should be in a folder named TeX in your Applications folder.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is my way to fix the problem I asked - I think it could be helpful.

1. Install the [Skim](http://skim-app.sourceforge.net/) PDF-viewer. It is free.
2. In [TeXmaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/) configuration  choose the external PDF-viewer and place there the following line:

   ```
    /Applications/Skim.app/Contents/SharedSupport/displayline @ %.pdf
   ```

   (I think it gives the possibility of the forward search.)
3. In the Skim preferences edit custom command in Sync section. The command must be:

   ```
   /Applications/texmaker.app/Contents/MacOS/texmaker
   ```

   with argument

   ```
   "%file" -line %line
   ```

Now you can perform the inverse search. How to do it? <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Command</kbd>-Click and the cursor moves to the corresponding place in the tex-file.

Comment: It seems that this does not work on my system. More specifically the second step (forward search) does not work. The other way around perfectly works. I suspect the reason is that I use a output folder and call the code with 

`/Applications/Skim.app/Contents/SharedSupport/displayline @ ./build/%.pdf`

and for some reason the document opens but with the first page. I checked but there seems to be no way to supply the location of the document.synctex.gz to skim. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

If you put the `-synctex=1` option in the following position then it works!!. At the end of the line it hasn't worked for me!!.

TexMaker -> Preferences -> Commands -> PdfLaTeX

```
"/usr/texbin/pdflatex" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

Answer (score 2):

I just found out that texmaker for mac supports forward/inverse search directly.

For forward search, you can go to your texmaker's preferences, in shortcuts menu, find the shortcut corresponds to VIEW PDF. Mine is F7, but yours might be different. After a double check, I found out that one need to quickly build twice, before you can make the forward search.

For inverse search, just press the command button, and click the text in the embedded pdf viewer, then you will go to the corresponding place in the tex file.

Answer (score 1):

Have you add the option

```
-synctex=1
```

for pdflatex, xelatex. However, version 2.2 can do forward/inverse search only on 1 files latex source.

Comment: Does this actually work on a Mac? I have v.2.2 and with -synctex=1 there is still no synching.

Comment: on Mac I don't know. One more possible mistake is pdfsync package. You should not use it.

Comment: @SBoonto But the question specifically asked about Mac.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Real solution (one possible) is in my own answer.

Comment: @Munn sorry for that. I just thought Texmaker is cross-platform editor and it use its own internal pdf viewer. In YouTube that I saw the solution at http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/log.html, is for Ubuntu. I used the same method on Windows XP,7 and it works very well. So I think may be this will work for Mac too.